# Highcharts / Highstock custom legend with labelFormatter event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please take a look at my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/newynct5/

The new legend code that's on the bottom I want to incorporate into the legend on the right. I've tried to add the same code that's in the create_new_legend(e) function (called in the xAxis afterSetExtremes and the chart load events) to the legend labelFormatter event, but the this.processedXData array is undefined, so I can't get the series' extreme values, and I am stuck. How do I do this?

```
$(function () {

  function create_new_legend(e) {

      var html = `
<table id="new-legend">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="price">Start</th>
    <th class="price">End</th>
    <th class="price">Change</th>
  </tr>
`;

      for (var i = 0; i < e.target.series.length; ++i) {
        var series_name = e.target.series[i].name;

        // Skip over the navigator.
        if (series_name.toLowerCase().trim() ==
            "Navigator".toLowerCase().trim())
        {
          continue;
        }

        var series_min_date = e.target.series[i].processedXData[1];
        var series_max_date = e.target.series[i].processedXData[
          e.target.series[i].processedXData.length - 1];

        var series_processed_y_data = e.target.series[i].processedYData;
        var series_min_y_data = series_processed_y_data[1].toFixed(2);
        var series_max_y_data = series_processed_y_data[series_processed_y_data.length - 1].toFixed(2);

        var series_data_change = ((series_max_y_data - series_min_y_data)/(series_min_y_data) * 100).toFixed(2);

        var series_css_class = (series_data_change > 0)
          ? 'pos' : ((series_data_change == 0)
                    ? 'zero' : 'neg');

        html += `
  <tr>
    <td class="stock">` + series_name + `</td>
    <td class="price">` + series_min_y_data + `</td>
    <td class="price">` + series_max_y_data + `</td>
    <td class="price"><span class="` + series_css_class + '">' + series_data_change + `%</td>
  </tr>
`;
      }

      html += `
</table>
`;
      $('#div-new-legend').html(html);

  } // end function do_this_after_set_extremes(e)

  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      events: {
        load: create_new_legend
      }
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      layout: 'vertical',
      width: 200,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 0.5,
      useHTML: true,
      labelFormatter: function() {
        var series_name = this.name;

        // this.processedXdata shows up fine in Firebug here...

        console.log("this:");
        console.log(this);

        // ...but here it's undefined!
        console.log("processedXData:");
        console.log(this.processedXData);

        // undefined
        var processed_x_data = this.processedXData;

        return this.name;
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: create_new_legend
      }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Microsoft',
        data: MSFT
    }, {
        name: 'Adobe',
        data: ADBE
    }, {
        name: 'Google',
        data: GOOGL
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, If you would like to have almost the same legend in your chart, maybe you can just use useHTML parameter of your legend? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML
Here you can see an example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/newynct5/9/

Comment: I don't like that at all. I've lost the helpful legend item symbols. Also, no matter which series I click on, only the Microsoft series is getting changed, so there's no way to disable the other two series. And all the series get dimmed when I move the mouse cursor away.

Comment: Hi, I can understand your opinion, the problem is that the legend is formatted before you can get information from your processedXData, that is why I have used load event callback function. You can for example get your data another way: https://jsfiddle.net/newynct5/12/, or change example I gave you so it will meet your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/newynct5/13/